# Why $y=e^x$ is not an algebraic curve?

Tags: exponential-function, algebraic-curves

Why $y=e^x$ is not an algebraic curve over $\mathbb R$? I can say that is not a algebraic curve over $\mathbb C$ because $e^x$ is a periodic function, but what about $\mathbb R$?

**EDIT:**

I don't want to use trascendence of $e$. Or, I can ask this question for $y=2^x$.

**UPDATE:**

Can we just say that algebraic curve over $K$ is also alegraic over any extension of $K$?

Comment: The question for $y=2^x$ is nicer because it does not mix things.

Comment: @lhf, it's definitely true.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Let $b > 1$ be a real number. If the function $y = b^{x}$ were algebraic, there would exist a positive integer $N$ and one-variable polynomial functions $p_{k}$, with $0 \leq k \leq N$ and $p_{N}$ is not identically zero, such that the polynomial
$$
f(x, y) = \sum_{k=0}^{N} p_{k}(x) y^{k}
$$
has zero set equal to the graph $y = b^{x}$. But this would imply
$$
0 = \sum_{k = 0}^{N} p_{k}(x) b^{kx}
  = b^{Nx} \sum_{k = 0}^{N} p_{k}(x) b^{(k - N) x}
\quad
\text{for all real $x$.}
\tag{1}
$$
Each term in the rightmost sum is a polynomial in $x$ multiplied by an exponential function with non-positive exponent. As $x \to \infty$, each term with $k < N$ approaches $0$. Since the term $p_{N}(x)$ is not identically $0$, equation (1) is false no matter how the $p_{k}$ are chosen.

Answer (score 6):

Suppose $x$ and $e^x$ satisfy a polynomial equation $f(x,e^x)=0$ where $f(x,y)$ has minimal degree in $y$.

Write $f(x,y)=p(x)y^n+g(x,y)$, where $p(x)y^n$ is the leading term in $y$.

Differentiate $p(x)e^{nx}+g(x,e^x)=0$ and get $np(x)e^{nx}+p'(x)e^{nx}+h(x,e^x)=0$, for some $h$.

Subtract $n$ times the first equation from the second and get $p'(x)e^{nx}+h(x,e^x)-ng(x,e^x)=0$.

This equation has a leading term $p'(x)e^{nx}$ of smaller degree in $x$.

We can repeat this process until we remove the term in $y^n$, which is a contradiction.

The same proof works for $b^x$ with some $\log b$ factors that can be absorbed.

Comment: Thanks, it's very cool. My professor advised me the same way.

Answer (score 3):

As I read in your post you accept that $y=e^x$ is not algebraic curve over $\mathbb{C}$. So assume that $y=e^x$ is algebraic over $\mathbb{R}$. That is to say that there is a non constant polynomial $p \in \mathbb{R}[X,Y]$ such that $$p(x,e^x) = 0$$ for all $x \in \mathbb{R}$.
Set $f(z) := p(z,e^z)$. Then $f : \mathbb{C} \to \mathbb{C}$ is a holomorphic function i.e. an entire function. The restriction of $f|_{\mathbb{R}}$ is zero. So by the identity principle $f$ is zero for all complex number. Then 
$$p(z,e^{z}) = 0$$
for all complex numbers hence $y=e^x$ is algebraic over the complex numbers.

Comment: Thanks, but complex analysis is a heavy artillery for such question:) Can we just say that algebraic curve over $K$ is also alegraic over any extension of $K$?

Answer (score 1):

An algebraic curve over $\mathbb{Q}$ is, by [definition](https://en.wikipedia.org/?title=Algebraic_curve) :

> a set of points on the Euclidean plane whose coordinates are zeros of
>   some polynomial in two variables with coefficients in $\mathbb{Q}$, i.e are algebraic numbers.

but $y=e^1=e$ is not an algebraic number (this can be proved as a consequence of  the [Lindemann–Weierstrass theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lindemann%E2%80%93Weierstrass_theorem)). so the coordinates of the point $(1,e)$ are not solutions of a polynomial equation with rational coefficients.

---

Added.

The above definition is valid for an algebraic curve over $\mathbb{Q}$, but can be extended to any field $K$:

> An algebraic (plane) curve is the graph of an equation $f(x,y)=0$
>   where $f(x,y)$ is a polynomial with coefficients in $K$.

The equation $y-2^x=0$ cannot be write as a polynomial.

Comment: Ok, I don't want use that $e$ is transcendental.

Comment: Michael: find the polynomial such that it equals $e^x$, or prove that there is no finite polynomial that equals $e^x$.

Comment: Is $y-e=0$ an algebraic curve or not?

Comment: The fact that $e$ is transcendental is completely irrelevant.