# Power series ring $k[[x]]$ contains elements transcendental over $k(x)$

Tags: abstract-algebra

If $k$ is countable, then $k[x]$ is countable and it seems easy to figure out $k[[x]]$ has elements transcendental over $k(x)$ because $k[[x]]$ is uncountable by using the fact that algebraic closure of countable field is countable. This seems okay theoretically. I start to work with example but it does not work for me. If $a\in k[[x]] - k(x)$ is algebraic over $k(x),$ then we have $$f_{0}(x) + f_{1}(x)a + f_{2}(x)a^2 + ... + f_{n}(x)a^n = 0,$$ where $f_{i}(x) \in k[x]$ for all $i = 0, 1,...,n.$  Is there any technique to show transcendental? Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

*Hint:* Prove that the exponential power series cannot be algebraic over $k(x)$, when char $k=0$.

Comment: See also http://math.stackexchange.com/q/1336692/589.